# Install Bluetooth Driver ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I want to install the driver for Bluetooth on my laptop. I have read a little on this forum about doing so but I still have little Knowledge about Ubuntu Still, and had a hard time understanding the commands I needed to do so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You provided no information that allows to suggest anything. You want to install a driver for Bluetooth. Why are you thinking that you really need it? Does Bluetooth work? If not than you need to start with finding out what is the BT hardware.

Comment: I mean I wouldn’t be asking if The Bluetooth was working. And as I said in the post I’m new to ubuntu software so I am unsure how to find out the BT hardware

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` command